# Not able to list S3 Buckets in react-native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working on a `react-native` mobile App for iOS and Android. I am trying to access `AWS` `S3` bucket using `aws-sdk` for `javascript`

Following are the steps I performed:

1. Install the `npm` on my `react-native` code
2. Import the library on my `javascript` class using `import AWS from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native`
3. Initialize `S3` using my `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`
4. Try to list the buckets in my `S3` folder. However I am getting the following error:

`{"message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your signing key and signing method, "code": "SignatureDoesNotMatch}`

Code Snippet:

```
var awsCred = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxx',
      secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    });

    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      region: 'my-region',
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
      credentials: awsCred,
    });

    var bucketParams = {
      Bucket: 'bucket_name',
    }; 

s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(err));
} else {
Alert.alert('Success', JSON.stringify(data));
}
});
```

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Double-check that the secret key is actually correct for the given access key. And make sure that this set of creds works with the awscli (`aws s3 ls mybucket --region x`).

Comment: @jarmod: I'm sure the `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` combination works fine. I tried retrieving the data using the credentials from one of the Chrome extensions and I was able to access the bucket without any issue. But the issue still persist on my `react-native` application

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the S3 constructor without the signature version. Simply using the credentials should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried that as well but running into the same error unfortunately